# Are the conjugate of analytic functions not analytic?

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers

I was writing the proof that $\overline {e^z}$ isn't analytic and I came up this question. Proof below:

$\overline {e^z} = e^x\cos{y} - e^xi\sin{y}$

Then, by Cauchy-Riemann:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^x\cos{y} \neq \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -e^x\cos{y}$$
and,

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -e^x\sin{y} \neq -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = e^x\sin{y}$$

I'd give a check since there may be calculation errors, but I think the opposing signs aren't by any chance a coincidence

Comment: I think this questions gives you some insight: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077999/if-fz-overline-fz-are-analytic-then-they-are-constant?rq=1

Comment: If all you're looking for is an example of a function which is analytic and such that its conjugate is non-analytic, then $f(z)=z$ is likely the simplest one possible.

Comment: @Snaw rather, I was looking for a function that is also analytic and its conjugate also is. By the link Conrad sent, I guess that's true only for constant functions

Comment: Trivially it is true for any constant, and by the link above these are the only options.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $f$ be any function satisfying the Cauchy--Riemann equations. Show that $\overline{f}$ satisfies the negated versions (i.e. with opposite signs) of the Cauchy--Riemann equations.